# EF4: ObjectSet.AddObject() not working

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am setting up a repository with Entity Framework 4, and I can't get the ObjectSet.AddObject() method working. Here is the code I am using--to keep things simple, I copied it out of the repository into my unit test method:

```
/* m_FilePath value is passed in by test initializer. */

// Configure a SQL CE connection string  
var sqlCompactConnectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0}", m_FilePath);

// Create an Entity Connection String Builder
var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.Metadata = string.Format("res://*/{0}.csdl|res://*/{0}.ssdl|res://*/{0}.msl", "Model.Notes");
builder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0";
builder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlCompactConnectionString;
var edmConnectionString = builder.ToString();

// Create object context and object set
var context = new NotesContainer(edmConnectionString);
var objectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<Note>();

// Add a note
var entity = new Note();
objectSet.AddObject(entity);

// Build assertion
var notes = objectSet.AsEnumerable();
var count = notes.Count();
Assert.AreEqual(1, count);
```

The count that is returned is zero--the object set is empty, so the assertion fails. When I step through the code, the object context and object set are created, but enumeration of the object set returns no results.

What's the error in my code? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `notes.Count()` is executed against your data file (which I assume is empty). Your new object won't be added until you call `context.SaveChanges()`.

Consider:

```
objectSet.AddObject(new Note()); // new object present in memory
var notes = objectSet.AsEnumerable();
var count = notes.Count();       // query against DB file; 
                                 // what's in memory at this point is irrelevant
```

Add `context.SaveChanges()` after you add new Note and assert will pass. But of course, that introduces whole new range of problems with keeping DB state the same for every test run.

Comment: ROFL! How could I forget that! Thanks--accepted and +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

That is not entirely true.

e.g. Parent / Childs

When using **Context.AddObject()** for **Parent** it won't be added to until **Context.SaveChanges()** is called but when adding a **Child** it *will be added without saving* (**when foreign keys are set of course**).

Not sure if it is a bug or if it is by design in the EF ...

The only "workaround" I see at the moment:

- introduce a Client table and each object (Parent, Child) has a reference to a Client
- call context.SaveChanges() (Drawback: the user has no chance to cancel the operation)

Also calling **Context.ParentSet.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);** does not have the expected effect!

**Solution/Workaround:** I maintain my own list of objects for adding/removing + setting the DataSource = null and then to my internal list.

Since it is necessary to set the DataSource = null it seems that there is something strange in EF ...